# Add Regular Expression Format check in addClassRules for Email validation (jQuery)?

Tags: jquery, regex, email-validation

I am trying to validate email only if it is entered.

I started with something like this.

```
$(function ($) {
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    $("#Email").blur(function () {
        var UserEmail = $(this).val();
        if (UserEmail.length > 0) {
            if (!emailReg.test(UserEmail)) {
                $("#Email").addClass("EmailFormat");
            }
            else {
                alert(UserEmail.length);
                $("#Email").removeClass("EmailFormat");
            }
        }
        else {
            $("#Email").removeClass("EmailFormat");
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.validator.addClassRules({
            EmailFormat: {
                required: true,
                regExpress: /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/,
                messages: { regExpress: "Invalid Email" }
            }
        });
    });
```

Can I get any help to get this work.

Comment: Why not save the regex induced headache just use jquery validate? It has the email check built in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got this worked like this.

```
  $("#Email").blur(function () {
    var UserEmail = $(this).val();
    if (UserEmail.length > 0) {
            $("#Email").addClass("EmailFormat");
    }
    else {
        $("#Email").removeClass("EmailFormat");
    }
 });
 $.validator.addClassRules({
EmailFormat: {
        regex:/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/
    }
});
jQuery.validator.messages.regex = 'Invalid Email';
```